# Jaeger is crash looping with error "file does not exist for table 6122"

Tags: kubernetes, jaeger, jaeger-client-go

We are using **Jeager in kubernets verion 1.21.7** and the **Jeager version is 1.29**. We are storing the Jeager logs in **Azure storage account**. Till now it was fine. When the pod dies and when the new pod spins, it is not able to access the **previous data and the container is crash looping**. Below is the error what I am getting

```
kubectl logs jaeger-75cddd55bf-48nss -n istio-system
2022/02/16 04:14:54 maxprocs: Leaving GOMAXPROCS=2: CPU quota undefined
{"level":"info","ts":1644984894.1548135,"caller":"flags/service.go:117","msg":"Mounting metrics handler on admin server","route":"/metrics"}
{"level":"info","ts":1644984894.1551123,"caller":"flags/service.go:123","msg":"Mounting expvar handler on admin server","route":"/debug/vars"}
{"level":"info","ts":1644984894.1556144,"caller":"flags/admin.go:104","msg":"Mounting health check on admin server","route":"/"}
{"level":"info","ts":1644984894.1557937,"caller":"flags/admin.go:115","msg":"Starting admin HTTP server","http-addr":":14269"}
{"level":"info","ts":1644984894.1560519,"caller":"flags/admin.go:96","msg":"Admin server started","http.host-port":"[::]:14269","health-status":"unavailable"}
badger 2022/02/16 04:14:54 ERROR: Received err: file does not exist for table 6122. Cleaning up...
{"level":"fatal","ts":1644984895.000993,"caller":"./main.go:107","msg":"Failed to init storage factory","error":"file does not exist for table 6122","stacktrace":"main.main.func1\n\t./main.go:107\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902\nmain.main\n\t./main.go:226\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:255"}
```

And Below is the **Jearger yaml** file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jaeger
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: jaeger
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jaeger
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jaeger
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "14269"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jaeger
          image: "docker.io/jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.29"
          env:
            - name: BADGER_EPHEMERAL
              value: "false"
            - name: SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE
              value: "badger"
            - name: BADGER_DIRECTORY_VALUE
              value: "/badger/data"
            - name: BADGER_DIRECTORY_KEY
              value: "/badger/key"
            - name: COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HOST_PORT
              value: ":9411"
            - name: MEMORY_MAX_TRACES
              value: "50000"
            - name: QUERY_BASE_PATH
              value: /jaeger
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 14269
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 14269
          volumeMounts:
            - name: azurefileshare
              mountPath: /badger
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
      volumes:
        - name: azurefileshare
          azureFile:
            secretName: log-storage-secret
            shareName: jaegerfileshare
            readOnly: false
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tracing
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: jaeger
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http-query
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 16686
    # Note: Change port name if you add '--query.grpc.tls.enabled=true'
    - name: grpc-query
      port: 16685
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 16685
  selector:
    app: jaeger
---
# Jaeger implements the Zipkin API. To support swapping out the tracing backend, we use a Service named Zipkin.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: zipkin
  name: zipkin
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9411
      targetPort: 9411
      name: http-query
  selector:
    app: jaeger
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jaeger-collector
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: jaeger
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: jaeger-collector-http
    port: 14268
    targetPort: 14268
    protocol: TCP
  - name: jaeger-collector-grpc
    port: 14250
    targetPort: 14250
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 9411
    targetPort: 9411
    name: http-zipkin
  selector:
    app: jaeger
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi @kiran are you able find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution, I deleted the entire directory where the Volume is, this space fills up over time,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).